# Function/app works locally in RStudio but not on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm trying to create a Shiny App where votes can be converted into seats using the Saint Lague method. An explanation of the exact process can be found here (https://www.bundeswahlleiter.de/en/service/glossar/s/sainte-lague-schepers.html). For this purpose I created my own function `saint_lague` which does this conversion. When I run the app locally in RStudio, I get the correct conversion after pressing the `Calculate` button and the data table is displayed correctly. However, when I run the app on `shinyapps.io`, I get the following error message:

```
Warning: Error in : Problem with `mutate()` column `seats`.
ℹ `seats = saint_lague(votes = votes, seats_tar = first(seats_state))`.
✖ Missing values where TRUE/FALSE needed
[No stack trace available]
```

I have already reduced the app to a minimum to be able to limit the error as much as possible. A reproducible example can be found attached.

The packages I use:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
```

The custom functions I use:

```
# function for exact rounding
round_pre <- function(x) {
        posneg = sign(x)
        z = abs(x) * 10 ^ 0
        z = z + 0.5 + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)
        z = trunc(z)
        z = z / 10 ^ 0
        z * posneg
    }

# finding a new divisor from a span
new_div <- function(div_range, descen) {
    divis <-
        Rfast::nth(
            x = div_range,
            k = 2,
            num.of.nths = 2,
            descending = descen
        ) %>%
        as.vector() %>%
        sort()
    
    divis_med <- median(divis)
    
    digit <- -6
    divis_r <- round(x = divis_med, digits = digit)
    new_div <- NULL
    
    while (is.null(new_div)) {
        if (divis_r > divis[1] & divis_r <= divis[2]) {
            new_div <- divis_r
        } else{
            digit <- digit + 1
            divis_r <- round(x = divis_med, digits = digit)
        }
    }
    
    return(new_div)
}

# saint lague function (calculation from votes to seats)
saint_lague <- function(votes, seats_tar) {
    divisor <- sum(votes, na.rm = TRUE) / seats_tar
    
    seats <- round_pre(votes / divisor)
    
    while (sum(seats) > seats_tar) {
        divisor_0.5 <- votes / (seats - 0.5)
        divisor_1.5 <- votes / (seats - 1.5)
        divisor_0.5 <- ifelse(divisor_0.5 < 0, NA, divisor_0.5)
        divisor_1.5 <- ifelse(divisor_1.5 < 0, NA, divisor_1.5)
        divisor <-
            new_div(div_range = c(divisor_0.5, divisor_1.5),
                    descen = FALSE)
        seats <- round_pre(votes / divisor)
    }
    
    while (sum(seats) < seats_tar) {
        divisor_0.5 <- votes / (seats + 0.5)
        divisor_1.5 <- votes / (seats + 1.5)
        divisor_0.5 <- ifelse(divisor_0.5 < 0, NA, divisor_0.5)
        divisor_1.5 <- ifelse(divisor_1.5 < 0, NA, divisor_1.5)
        divisor <-
            new_div(div_range = c(divisor_0.5, divisor_1.5),
                    descen = TRUE)
        seats <- round_pre(votes / divisor)
    }
    
    return(seats)
}
```

The Data I use:

```
df <-
    tibble(
        votes = c(119566, 388399, 64238, 220039, 322763, 494055, 55578),
        seats_state = 22
    )
```

The shiny app:

```
# ui
ui <-
    fluidPage(sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
        actionButton(inputId = "calc", label = "Calculate")
    ), mainPanel(DTOutput(outputId = "seats"))))

# server
server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$calc, {
        df_out <-
            df %>%
            mutate(seats = saint_lague(votes = votes, seats_tar = first(seats_state)))
        output$seats <- renderDT(df_out)
    })
    
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Did you ran the app locally in a fresh R session clearing clearing all the global environment variables ?

Comment: It doesn't work locally for me.  It works only if I do `df[1:6,]`.  If I increase `seats_state` to 44 in your dataframe `df`, it works fine.  So, I think you may be running into limitations of your function `saint_lague()` when the number of seats is low.